# AWS Autoscaling Thinks Dead Instance is Alive

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

My autoscaling group in AWS is all messed up... I tried scaling down, but for some reason it wasn't terminating the instances... they just stayed stuck at "Terminating:Wait" for hours. So I gave up and just terminated them manually, but now they're still there in the Auto Scaling group's Instance list, saying "Terminating:Wait" even though they **no longer exist in any way**.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Are they listed by the Load Balancer?

Comment: Its worth pointing out it is possible to have an ASG Without a Load balancer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem.  I wanted to destroy my Auto Scaling Group, but the lifecycle hook was causing issues.  Specifically, the status of the instance (as listed under instances on the ASG console) was `terminating:wait` while the instance was marked as `terminated` on the regular EC2 instance console.

After some Googling, here's what I figured out.  If you'd like to manually "ABANDON" the lifecycle hook on the instance that's causing you an issue, here's how you do that (with the AWS CLI):

```
aws autoscaling complete-lifecycle-action \
  --lifecycle-hook-name ${LIFECYCLE_HOOK_NAME} \
  --auto-scaling-group-name ${ASG_NAME} \
  --lifecycle-action-result ABANDON \
  --instance-id ${EC2_INSTANCE_ID}
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/complete-lifecycle-action.html

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you have [Lifecycle Hooks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/lifecycle-hooks.html) activated on your Auto Scaling group.

When an instance is terminated with a Lifecycle Hook active, the instance is not immediately terminated. Rather, it is placed into the `Terminating:Wait` state and a message is sent via SNS or SQS to signal the pending termination. You are meant to have a process that receives this message, does whatever it needs to do (eg copy off log files) and then **signals** that the instance may be terminated.

If the termination signal is **not received after 90 minutes**, the instance will be **terminated**. So, you'll probably find they are gone now.

It's very strange to have Lifecycle Hooks activated unintentionally because they can only be added via an API call.

Comment: Yeah, they disappeared eventually. I never added Lifecycle Hooks as far as I know.